# pyMongo iterate over cursor object with subitems

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The function below searches a collection with a subitem projects. If there is a subitem with `isManager` set to 1 it should return `True` otherwise it will always return `False`.

```
def isMasterProject(self, pid, uid):
  masterProjects = False
  proj = self.collection.find({ "_id": uid, "projects": { '$elemMatch': { "projectId": _byid(pid), "isManager": 1 } } })
  for value in proj:
    if str(value['projects']['projectId']) == pid:
      if value['projects']['isManager'] == 1:
        masterProjects = True
  return masterProjects
```

`_byid` is equivalent to ObjectId

It always seem to return `False`. Here's an example of a collection.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52cf683306bcfc7be96a4d89"),
  "firstName" : "Test",
  "lastName" : "User",
  "projects" : [
    {
      "projectId" : ObjectId("514f593c06bcfc1e96f619be"),
      "isManager" : 0
    },
    {
      "projectId" : ObjectId("511e3ed0909706a6a188953d"),
      "isManager" : 1
    },
    {
      "projectId" : ObjectId("51803baf06bcfc149116bf62"),
      "isManager" : 1
    },
    {
      "projectId" : ObjectId("514362bf121f92fb6867e58f"),
      "isManager" : 1
    }
  ],
  "user" : "test.user@example.com",
  "userType" : "Basic"
}
```

Would it be simpler to check for an empty cursor and if so how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
obj = next(proj, None)
if obj:
```

[$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) should only return results if the criteria given match a document so you should only return a cursor from **find** where your criteria are true.

Since you are using `_id` in the query and only ever expect to get one result, why not use **findOne** and shortcut one step.

Another **gotcha** for the new initiates, be aware you are returning the whole document here and not some representation with only the matching element of the array. Things that did not match will still be there, and then expecting different results by iterating over these will lead you to grief.

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the reference/reminder to the elemMatch documentation. I agree completely with findOne and have update my definition accordingly and my lame key iteration which seems to have done the trick. Thanks again @neil-lunn